# Finding mean, standart deviation and density function of a RV

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, random-variable, density-function

I'm new at learning random variables and stuck in this example. Can anyone help me solve this?
"The RV **x** is N(5,2) and **y**=2**x**+4. Find mean, standard deviation and density function of y."

Comment: What *exactly* is unclear for you?

Comment: I just processed definition equations (mean of y is integral of g(x) which is equal 2x+4 and gaussian density function fx) and it went hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(5,2)$ $-$ assuming 2 is the *standard deviation* $-$ and $Y = 2X+4$. We have:

- **Mean**: by linearity of expectation, we get:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[2X+4] = 2\mathbb{E}[X]+4 = 2\times5+4=15$$

- **Standard deviation**:

$$\mathbb{V}[Y] = \mathbb{V}[2X+4] = \mathbb{V}[2X] = 4\mathbb{V}[X] = 4\times4 = 16$$

- **Density function**: the density of a random variable $f$ corresponds to the derivative of its cumulative distribution function (CDF) $F$; moreover, if $g$ and $h$ are two functions, then the derivative of $g \, \circ \, h(x)=g(h(x)) $ is $h'(x)g'(h(x))$. Hence letting $F_Y$ be the CDF of $Y$ and $f_Y$ its density $-$ and analogously for $X$:

$$ \begin{align}
f_Y(z) & = \frac{dF_Y}{dz}(z)
\\[8pt]
& = \frac{d}{dz}\mathbb{P}(Y \leq z)
\\[8pt]
& = \frac{d}{dz}\mathbb{P}(2X+4 \leq z)
\\[8pt]
& = \frac{d}{dz}\mathbb{P}(X \leq \frac{z-4}{2})
\\[8pt]
& = \frac{dF_X}{dz}\left(\frac{z-4}{2}\right)
\\[8pt]
& = \frac{1}{2}f_X\left(\frac{z-4}{2}\right)
\end{align} $$